# Loss of information using categorical variables

Tags: categorical-data

I am new to data science, and I would like to know whether I can use *n-1* categorical variables instead of the original *n*, without risking to lose information.

At example: I have three categorical variables *A*,*B*,*C*, and I write *C* in function of *A* and *B*, therefore I have reduced the number of variables from *3* to *2*. Can I apply this reduction without loss the information of the original *3* variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only can you do this, but, in most parameterizations, it is required that you do so.  Usually, one level is taken as the reference and the others are compared to it. You can also compare all levels to the overall mean, but I find that less intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Dummy coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable#Dummy_coding) article on Wikipedia?

> In dummy coding, the reference group is assigned a value of 0 for each code variable, the group of interest for comparison to the reference group is assigned a value of 1 for its specified code variable, while all other groups are assigned 0 for that particular code variable.[2]

Comment: I have read this article, but I wanted to be completely sure that it's still true when I'm implementing this on  ANN, as in my case.